# Cascade ="all" not saving child entities

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, cascade

I *think* the object model below is saying a Party and PartyName to have a many to one relatioship. An I think the cascade=all i the Party.hbm sshould be having NHib save the child PartyName(s).

But it clearly isn't...

Can someone explain why PartyName isn't being saved with Party and what to do to fix?

Cheers,
Berryl

[image]

## MAPPING

```
<class name="Party" table="Parties">
<id name="Id">
  <column name="PartyId" />
  <generator class="hilo" />
</id>

<discriminator column="Type" not-null="true" type="string" />

<set access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="all" inverse="true" name="Names">
  <key foreign-key="Party_PartyName_FK">
    <column name="PartyNameId" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Parties.Domain.Names.PartyName, Parties.Domain" />
</set>

<subclass 
  name="Smack.Core.TestingSupport.NHibernate.TestableDomain.SomeDopeyDomainModel.Student, Smack.Core.TestingSupport" 
  discriminator-value="Student"
  >
  <property name="Number" />

  <many-to-one 
    class="Smack.Core.TestingSupport.NHibernate.TestableDomain.SomeDopeyDomainModel.Course, Smack.Core.TestingSupport" 
    foreign-key="Course_FK" 
    name="Course">
    <column name="CourseId" index="CourseIndex" />
  </many-to-one>
</subclass>
```

```
<many-to-one access="field.camelcase-underscore" class="Parties.Domain.Party" foreign-key="Party_FK" name="Party">
  <column name="PartyId" index="PartyIndex" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
<property name="TheRequiredName" not-null="true" length="50"/>
<property name="EverythingElse" />
<property name="ContextUsed" length="50"/>
<property name="Salutation" length="20"/>
<property name="EffectivePeriod" type="Smack.Core.Data.NHibernate.UserTypes.DateRangeUserType, Smack.Core.Data">
  <column name="EffectiveStart"/>
  <column name="EffectiveEnd"/>
</property>
```

## Failing Test (and output)

```
    [Test]
    public void CanSaveAndLoad_AllProperties()
    {
        var partyName = NameSeeds.DevName;
        partyName.Party = _party;
        Assert.That(_party.Names.First(), Is.EqualTo(partyName));


        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _session.Save(_party);
            tx.Commit();
        }
        _session.Clear();

        Party foundParty;
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foundParty = _session.Get<Party>(_party.Id); *** <=== name s/b saved!!
            tx.Commit();
        }
        PartyName foundName = foundParty.Names.First();
        //found.Look();

        Assert.That(foundName, Is.EqualTo(partyName));
        Assert.That(foundName.Party, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(foundName.TheRequiredName, Is.EqualTo(partyName.TheRequiredName));
        Assert.That(foundName.EverythingElse, Is.EqualTo(partyName.EverythingElse));
        Assert.That(foundName.ContextUsed, Is.EqualTo(partyName.ContextUsed));
        Assert.That(foundName.Salutation, Is.EqualTo(partyName.Salutation));
        Assert.That(foundName.EffectivePeriod, Is.EqualTo(partyName.EffectivePeriod));
    }


NHibernate: INSERT INTO Parties (Type, PartyId) VALUES ('Parties.Domain.Party', @p0);@p0 = 32768 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate: SELECT party0_.PartyId as PartyId2_0_, party0_.Number as Number2_0_, party0_.CourseId as CourseId2_0_, party0_.Type as Type2_0_ FROM Parties party0_ WHERE party0_.PartyId=@p0;@p0 = 32768 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the mapping of the Names `<set>` `inverse=true`, you will have to explicitly call session.Save(partyNameObject) on each member of the collection. If you are looking to have NHibernate automatically save the members of the set when the PartyObject is saved, you need to change the Names `<set>` inverse attribute to `inverse=false`. This tells Nhibernate that you want Party to control the relationship between Party and PartyName. You must also remember to add each partyNameObject to the Party.Names collection. Otherwise, they won't be saved when you call `Session.Save(partyObject)`. Keep in mind that having the parent control the relationship may be handy, but if you happen to save the PartyObject without having Loaded the PartyNames collection, NHibernate will update their Party FK to Null. In this scenario with certain Cascade options set on the Names `<set>`, you might find Nhibernate Deleting them as well.

Comment: Makes sense it doesnt work (Party still doesn't save PartyNme)

Comment: Missed some details in my first response and updated my answer.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this, and out together a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797101/nhibernate-bidirectional-mapping) to try and get everythinh nailed down. Have a look - Cheers